# Как выделить слово из строки и присвоить его переменной?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Получаю список файлов на ftp сервере в виде строки:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 10473 10473 0    Oct 13 09:18 rtrt.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 10473 10473 3091 Oct 13 09:16 test2.txt
```

как из него можно выделить только слова с определенным расширением, например .txt и записать их в переменную?

Файлов в выводе может быть больше и имена самых файлов неизвестны, только расширение.

Поиск grep'ом выводит всю строку , а мне нужно именно слова

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. чтобы было удобнее работать с именами файлов, можно получать ведь не полный листинг, а только имена файлов. например, если используете программу *curl*, то с помощью опции `--list-only`:

   ```
   $ curl --list-only ftp://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/doc/
   00-INDEX
   FAQ
   bug-log-access.txt
   bug-log-mailserver.txt
   bug-mailserver-refcard.txt
   bug-maint-info.txt
   bug-maint-mailcontrol.txt
   bug-reporting.txt
   constitution.txt
   debian-manifesto
   dedication
   mailing-lists.txt
   social-contract.txt
   source-unpack.txt
   ```
2. с помощью программы *grep* из этого списка можно отобрать только те имена, которые заканчиваются суффиксом `.txt`:

   ```
   $ curl -s --list-only ftp://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/doc/ | grep '\.txt$'
   bug-log-access.txt
   bug-log-mailserver.txt
   bug-mailserver-refcard.txt
   bug-maint-info.txt
   bug-maint-mailcontrol.txt
   bug-reporting.txt
   constitution.txt
   mailing-lists.txt
   social-contract.txt
   source-unpack.txt
   ```

   я добавил ещё опцию `-s`, чтобы программа *curl* не формировла прогресс выполнения в *stderr* (что она делает, если *stdout* вместо терминала отправляется на *stdin* другой программе).

   `grep '\.txt$'` — здесь обратный слэш нужен для того, чтобы точка трактовалась как символ точки, а не как квантификатор, означающий «один любой символ». а `$` — это квантификатор привязки к концу строки.
3. ну а полученный список уже можно и в переменную поместить:

   ```
   $ v=$(curl -s --list-only ftp://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/doc/ | grep '\.txt$')
   $ echo $v
   bug-log-access.txt bug-log-mailserver.txt bug-mailserver-refcard.txt bug-maint-info.txt bug-maint-mailcontrol.txt bug-reporting.txt constitution.txt mailing-lists.txt social-contract.txt source-unpack.txt
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно!

Comment: @Andrey  [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Можно было и про `grep -o ...` рассказать.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, наверное:

```
ls -l | cut -c50-120 | tail -n +1 | grep txt
```

Команда *tail* используется для пропуска первой строки, содержащей заголовок