# Как найти в списке нужную позицию?

Tags: python

Подключаюсь к ftp серверу получаю содержание в виде списка

> -rw-r--r--   1 1003     1003        12064 Jan 25 10:59 220125.rar

> -rw-r--r--   1 1003     1003        12063 Jan 26 11:00 220126.rar

> -rw-r--r--   1 1003     1003        12064 Jan 27 11:00 220127.rar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хочу проверить в списке наличие нужной мне записи, но данная конструкция

```
ftp = FTP(Серверftp)

date = '220122.rar'
date1 = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
if date in date1:
    print("Есть в списке")
else:
    print("Нет в списке")
```

не находит я так понимаю, что список нужно подготовить но как?

Comment: то, что в вопросе - не список. Что печатает print(date1)?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос, что содержит `date1`. Пары членов списка будет достаточно

Comment: @Эникейщик что содержит видно на скрине

Comment: Ну так вот, на скрине - не список.

Comment: @Dmitry на скрине

Comment: прикольно... ну ок, берите реализацию для распознования текста с картинки и обрабатывайте

Comment: @Dmitry не понял вас вам из вывода в консоль текст нужен?

Comment: @Эникейщик хорошо не список а что?

Comment: у вас есть переменная `date1`, вы в ней организуете поиск подстроки `date`. Так мы хотим увидеть где вы ищете. Выведе в консоль, скопируйте пару значений из списка (это вообще список?) и вам дадут однозначный вариант решения

Comment: как ты думаешь, для чего два человека попросили привести тебя пример данных? Именно для того, что посмотреть что это.

Comment: @Dmitry добавил

Comment: @Эникейщик пример данных как правило хватала скрина.

Comment: да, вижу, только в общем понимании это строка, тип данных не лист. Проблема понять, что за тип данных, то что в документации пишут лист им не является. Методы обработки строк и списков отличаются

Comment: @Dmitry предлагаете для сравнения целую строку забивать сразу скажу побывал не работает

Comment: вообще нет, секунду дайте)

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194257/178576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [ftplib.FTP.nlst](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst) вместо [ftplib.FTP.retrlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines). `ftp.nlst()` возвращает спискок имён файлов в каталоге. Пользоваться гораздо проще:

```
from ftplib import FTP


ftp = FTP('ftp.us.debian.org')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('debian')
print('README' in ftp.nlst())
print('UGU' in ftp.nlst())
```

> ```
> $ python search.py
> True
> False
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Пошли в [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines):

> The default callback prints the line to sys.stdout

> Обратный вызов по умолчанию выводит строку в `sys.stdout`

Это может означать что `date1` вообще не содержит каких либо данных, кроме объекта вызова функции. Вопрос, так что же содержит переменная `date1`? К сожалению, у меня нет тестовых ftp. Но вы можете сделать явно

```py
date1 = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
print(date1)
```

Чтобы увидеть содержание `date1`

Переделываем, добавляя callback

```
date1 = []
ftp.retrlines("LIST", date1.append)
```

А далее используем это

```py
date = "220127.rar"
position = None

for counter, value in enumerate(date1):
    if date in value:
        position = counter
```

Comment: В консоль так же выводит результат но с print(position)  добавляется или по другому
    print("Нет в списке")

Comment: дополнил, вывод в консоль не значит, что данные содержатся в переменной

Comment: В переменная position теперь содержится 687, но теперь в консоль нечего не выводится.

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ да, потому что вы переопределили `callback` с "по умолчанию выводить в консоль" на "добавить в список "date1"". А ваш искомый файл находится в строке под номером 687, начиная отсчет с нуля.

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ в методе `retrlines(cmd, callback)`, в callback вы можете передавать функцию, которая может содержать несколько операций над данными и добавление в список, и вывод в консоль, например

Answer (score 0):

Если это список строк, то как-то так можно проверить наличие строки в любой из строк списка:

```
if any(date in line for line in date1):
```

А ваша проверка сработает только если целая строка списка в точности равна искомой строке. Но судя по всему там не только же название файла есть.

Comment: выдаёт ошибку     if any(date in line for line in date1):
NameError: name 'date' is not defined

Comment: Странно, у вас же `date = "220127.rar"` ранее